# Ranorex 8/8.1 calling an external assembly written under .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, ranorex

Im new to ranorex, and i need to know if i can reference a .dll written in csharp under the .net framework 4.6.1 that allows me to do some data setup prior to testing.

I want to use ranorex studio ide still, and not have to export tests to visual studio. Essentially just call a method in this assembly. Can this be Done? I keep hearing ranorex does not support 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed already, a Ranorex solution is basically a Visual Studio solution.
I have just verified in Ranorex and the target framework of a Ranorex project can be set to 4.6.

Hence, calling a function from another DLL would simply required that you add a reference to that DLL and then call it from user code.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It supports Ranorex 4.6. Awesome. Can it support 4.6.1?

Comment: For your info, someone asked basically the same question on Ranorex forums: https://www.ranorex.com/forum/ranorex-8-and-net-4-6-1-t11884.html. You could try changing the target framework in Visual Studio and see if it still works.